# Why they use "while" statement when reading from an inputstream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I found this small piece of code on [android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html):

```
MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
int byteCount;
while ((byteCount = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    digester.update(bytes, 0, byteCount);
}
byte[] digest = digester.digest();
```

My question is: what would happen if I replace "while" with "if" ?

Comment: Emm... it will execute only once.

Comment: You'll read at most 8192 bytes total.

Comment: you will only read a chunk of 8192 bytes once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code on android.com shows how to generate a `MD5` hash from an `InputStream`.
You don't know how many bytes are in the stream, do you?
As long as you don't know this you have to loop.

Now to your question:

> My question is: what would happen if I replace "while" with "if" ?

You can only generate MD5 hashs on InputStreams that provide 8192 or less bytes.

or expressed in another way:

The MD5 hash might only be valid up to 8192 bytes of the InputStream.

**Note**: The InputStream can only read as much bytes as currently available. So even if the source of the InputStream contains more than 8192 bytes a read(byte[8192]) might only read 10, 5 or even no bytes.

See also the comment of U Mad.

Comment: `The MD5 hash is only valid up to 8192 bytes of the InputStream.`

Note that InputStream contract for method `read` does not require the InputStream to actually fill the buffer completely. Let's say the actual stream length is 1 MB, and you call `read` with buffer of size 8192. The stream can return just one byte or zero or ten, even though that's much less than buffer size or stream size. This rarely happens, but you must account for that possibility. That is why the return value of `read` must be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly because the length of the `Stream` is generally unknown or unreliable and because they are reading "chunks" of a the stream at a time.

You can argue, "but I'm read from a file", but this approach allows you the flexibility to abstract the process in such away as you don't care where you're reading from.

Answer (score 0):

If you would do such a replacement, what will happen is that, if the condition holds, the segment within the braces will be executed only once.

The while is there to keep on iterating in such a way that the buffer is gradually populated.

This is the usual way in which data is read from streams.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
If --> conditional statement
```

(checks the condition and executed statements only once if the condition is satisfied)

```
while --> looping statement
```

(will exexute the statements as long as condition is satisfied)

Answer (score 0):

```
what would happen if I replace "while" with "if" ?
```

Simply you can't have loop there and execute only one time.

```
 while(condition)// this will run while condition is true 

 if(condition)// this will execute if condition is true only there is no looping
```